Is Ng2SearchPipeModule not compatible with Angular Ivy ( Angular 16)?
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:28:5 - error NG6002: 'Ng2SearchPipeModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
node_modules/ng2-search-filter/src/ng2-filter.module.d.ts:1:22
1 export declare class Ng2SearchPipeModule {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The Ng2SearchPipeModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy, the complier used in Angular16 and latest version. This is due to the significant changes introduced in Angular, which have rendered many older libraries and modules incompatible.
If you are using Angular16 or later, you will need to find an alternative search pipe module that is compatible with Ivy. There are several options available, including:

ng-search-pipe
ngx-search-pipe


This is an outdated library. It wasn't built for Ivy and Angular v16 dropped the support for non-ivy libraries.
You really shouldn't rely on libraries that haven't been updated for so long (more than 5 years in this case).
